# Displaying the first element of the div in different color

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am doing this in my view :

```
<div class="eight columns">
    <div class="content">
        <%= post.text %>
    </div>
</div>
```

This displays my posts in a separate block of divs I want the first post to be of different color.

I tried `.content:first-child { background-color: red;}` but it doesn't seem to work.

**Update**

Actual HTML Output :-

```
 <div class="eight columns">
        <div class = "speech">
          <p>Has anyone got a clue about this?</p>
        </div>
 </div>
```

Any ideas how can I achieve the desired result?

Comment: Which element is "the first post"? The `<div class = "speech">`?

Comment: yes <div class = "speech"> is the first post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried `.content:first-child { background-color: red;}` but it doesn't seem to work.

---

You're missing the space in between, which targets child elements:

```
.content .speech:first-child { background-color: red;}
```

This will select every first `.speech` element that's a child of `.content`. The space is needed to select children ***of*** the `.content` element rather than the `.content` element itself.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RbBcD/2/

Originally, I mistakenly said to use `.content :first-child` which is much too broad, as it will select *every* first child in the entire `.content` element. However, `.content > :first-child` could work as well but I don't necessarily recommend it here.

More on `:first-child`: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-firstchild

Comment: .content:first-child{background-color: red;} makes all the posts background in red color

Comment: Yes, see update. You're selecting the `.content` element itself and not the children. If this doesn't work, you need to post your actual HTML output.

Comment: somehow it is giving the 2nd post no color and all the other post a red background

Comment: @DevR: I suggested a selector that was *waay* too broad.  `element :first-child` would select *every* first child in the tree. Use the class name in the selector,  like `.speech:first-child`. My mistake, I apologize - see edit.

Comment: Curious, why don't you necessarily recommend the child selector here? I'd definitely use it.

Comment: @BoltClock You mean `.content > :first-child`? Because it could potentially select unwanted elements on other pages or other parts if the same page, or if he wraps the elements in a div he won't have to change the selector. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: I mean something like `.content > .speech:first-child`, but you're right, using the descendant selector is convenient as "if he wraps the elements in a div he won't have to change the selector".